# How to hide actual path of url using .htaccess?

Tags: domain, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My domain `mainsite.com` is actual pointed to `/public_html/` .

But i want to point it to sub-site like `/public_html/subsite` .

So i tried this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(subsite) /subsite%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

It working fine .

Now 2nd is i have many sub-site/sub-folder under `/public_html/subsite` like `/public_html/subsite/(site1 or others...)` .

But when i type `mainsite.com/(site1 or others...)` then it showing me this url `mainsite.com/subsite/(site1 or others...)` which i don't want.

I want to hide only `/subsite/` from url when user browse.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to redirect the web browser to the new URL, or do you want to keep the web browser showing the original URL but show the content from a different path? Or something else?

Comment: Ok I updated.... @Tim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: When someone browse `www.mydomain.com/error/` this url, which actual path is `www.mydomain.com/site1/error/` so i want to hide `/site1/` wihout changing url.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Debar You should clarify your question a bit. Start by adding what you said in your last comment (I think).

Comment: Your second rewrite rule says if it doesn't have subsite in the URL.. redirect to it.  If that's not the behavior you want, why put the rule in?

Comment: Ok can you understand my question what i want? If you understand please give a example how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have multiple domains? It's not clear why your rule is triggering an _external redirect_ (ie. the URL is changing) - the rule you have posted is an _internal rewrite_. Clear your browser cache to make sure no erroneous redirects have been cached.

Comment: Yes i have multiple domain for same hosting account. But i want to show different for each domain using  htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Read this info about setting up an alias:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

> The **Alias** directive allows documents to be stored in the local
>   filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot. URLs with a (%-decoded)
>   path beginning with URL-path will be mapped to local files beginning
>   with directory-path. The URL-path is case-sensitive, even on
>   case-insensitive file systems.
>
> ```
> Alias "/image" "/ftp/pub/image"
> ```
>
> A request for
>   http://example.com/image/foo.gif would cause the server to return the
>   file **/ftp/pub/image/foo.gif**. Only complete path segments are matched,
>   so the above alias would not match a request for
>   http://example.com/imagefoo.gif. For more complex matching using
>   regular expressions, see the **AliasMatch** directive.